# PHP exec() causes g++ error with cc1plus

Tags: php, c++

I'm trying to compile C++ programs through PHP's exec() function. The command works when running directly from the command line and the program compiles perfectly, but in PHP exec() the error `g++: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory` surfaces.

I am running PHP-FPM 7.1 with the user www-data.

In PHP the command in question is `exec('g++ /home/username/example.cpp -o main.o 2>&1', $out);`

Comment: The shell in which g++ is executing does not have the same value for the PATH variable that your command line shell has.

Comment: ... and if your web server really has the ability to execute your compiler, you better hope that your web server is not Internet-accessible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the user your php script runs as has a different PATH variable than your own user.
By using `exec( echo $PATH)` you should see that the PATH variable is different than if you use `echo $PATH` on your command line.
Try to use the full path to g++, you can find it by using `which g++`.

Comment: I'm getting `collect2: fatal error: cannot find 'ld'
compilation terminated.`, what should I do?